# VBA: Over-writing cell with multiple IF conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write a VBA macro to give a specific value when two conditions are met, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do so, and searching doesn't help me with my specific issue.

Here's a quick summary of the problem:

I want to over-write the value in a specific cell if the values in two other cells match something specific.

I have a working code for the same report that over-writes a value if one other value matches something specific, and here is the code for that:

```
Sub test_overwrite()

Dim msheet As Worksheet

Set msheet = ActiveSheet

'Overwrites for test and reactivated cells

  For i = 2 To msheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
   Select Case msheet.Cells(i, 7)
   Case Is = "test"
    msheet.Cells(i, 5) = "test"
   Case Is = "reactivated"
    msheet.Cells(i, 5) = "reactivated"
   End Select

Next i

End Sub
```

Basically, what I would like to add to this code is the ability to overwrite a cell in (i,7) if the value of (i,5) matches "expired" and the value of (i,6) matches "#N/A".

How would I do so?

Edit 1:

Here's something I have just tried, but I get an 'Object Required' error

```
Sub subs_test_new_tests()

'Mark certain fields that are 'expired' as 'test'

Dim msheet As Worksheet
Dim state As String
Dim match As String
Dim status As String

Set msheet = ActiveSheet

For i = 2 To msheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Set state = msheet.Cells(i, 5)
Set match = msheet.Cells(i, 6)
Set status = msheet.Cells(i, 7)

If state = "expired" And match = "#N/A" Then
status = "test"

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use a simple `IF condition1 And condition2 then` statement.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example? I have tried that before, using stuff I found on message boards/here, but haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub subs_test_new_tests()

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If .Cells(i, 5) = "expired" Then
            If .Cells(i, 6) = "#N/A" Or Application.IsNA(.Cells(i, 6)) Then
                .Cells(i, 7) = "test"
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I had to remove `.Cells(i, 6) = "#N/A" Or` from line 5, but otherwise that works now. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `IsError(.Cells(i,6).Value)` instead of `.Cells(i, 6) = "#N/A"` to check if there are errors in your cells

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test_overwrite()
Dim msheet As Worksheet
Set msheet = ActiveSheet
With msheet
'Overwrites for test and reactivated cells
  For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count

   Select Case Trim(.Cells(i, 7).Text)

   Case Is = "test"
      Trim(.Cells(i, 5).Text) = "test"
   Case Is = "reactivated"
      Trim(.Cells(i, 5).Text) = "reactivated"
   End Select

   if Trim(.Cells(i, 5).Text) = "expired" And  ISERROR(.Cells(i, 6)) then  .Cells(i, 7) = "test"

Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an 'Object Required' error on line 12, the first (Trim(msheet.Cells line